# AWS What is the difference between subnet and subnet mapping?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, subnet

Elastic Load Balancing v2 offers 2 options regarding networking: [subnets and subnet mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-subnetmappings). However, I could not find the difference between the 2 of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Subnet mappings - are mostly usefull with a network load balancers where you can specify an IP for an internet-facing loadbalancer as AllocationId, IPv6Addresses, PrivateIPv4Address, SubnetID.
- Subnets - IPs are assigned randomly, from a subnets specified CIDR range.

Ref.:
[Subnet Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_SubnetMapping.html), [Subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-subnets)